# use plainToClass in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor, class-transformer

I have a constructor that assigns properties to the instance:

```
class BaseModel {
    constructor (args = {}) {
        for (let key in args) {
            this[key] = args[key]
        }
    }
}

class User extends BaseModel {
    name: string
}
```

Then I can create an instance like this:

```
let user = new User({name: 'Jon'})
```

I would now like to replace this basic functionality with class-transformer:

`let user = plainToClass(User, {name: 'Jon'})`

My codebase uses the first approach in many places and I would therefore like to implement the new way in the constructor so I don't break the old code:

```
 constructor (args = {}) {
        let instance = plainToClass(CLASSTYPE, args)
        for (let key in Object.keys(instance)) {
            this[key] = instance [key]
        }
    }
```

How can I get the class type in the constructor? I cannot use User because this is the base model and other classes may also extend from it.

Comment: I think you should call the constructor from `plainToClass`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's `new.target`. [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)
To get constructor use `new.target.prototype.constructor`, and it's property `name` - to get class name.

```
class BaseModel {
    typeName: string;

    constructor (args = {}) {
        this.typeName = new.taget.constructor.name;
    }
}

class User extends BaseModel {
}

const user = new User();
const typeName = user.typeName; // this would return 'User'
```